# how many “real-life people” do you know who participate on stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, profile-page

By "real-life", I mean people you know in real-life (such as co-workers), not just from the internet. From my friends that are developers, or from colleagues at work, a fair amount of them say they use stackoverflow. For the ones who claim they don't use stackoverflow, I find that hard to believe. But it might be somehow possible that they get all their questions answered without ever having to ask one.

However, nobody I know has told me of their stackoverflow profile name. Could it be that the vast majority of developers only use stackoverflow passively, or maybe that most don't want to admit they have or share their stackoverflow profile?

Comment: Knowing someone personally is not a requirement for participation, nor is it even an enhancing element, necessarily.  I am aware of at least one other person at work who participates, but I don't broadcast my participation, nor does he, because I don't want to be perceived (rightly or wrongly) as someone who spends work time doing this.

Comment: I was using stack overflow for about a year before ever I created an account. All the questions I had up to that point were already asked and answered.

Comment: Maybe they're not telling you their profile name for another reason entirely

Comment: to the downvoters: what don't you like about this question?

Comment: @random: I considered appending that catch-all at the end, but it seemed too obvious have to spell it out.

Comment: @T.Webster welcome to Meta.SO ... here downvotes mean anything from "I agree but don't like the question" to "I disagree with the views presented in this question" to "this is totally wrong" ... there's not much to be done about downvotes in general without comments, and here doubly so. C'est la vie. Welcome to MSO.

Comment: All of my coworkers use Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange. (:

Answer (score 8, accepted):

None.

Various responses when I've chatted with others about it (almost all the programmers I've talked with about it were aware of it):

- Meh.
- Good luck getting answers about `expert programming issue` there (you're right, no responses, but if I keep trying, and look for those I can answer, maybe we can build up that extra 1% level of expertise that's currently missing)
- I have no questions I need answered, and I'm not interested in answering other people's questions - I've got work to do.

Comment: At some point in 2011 you started posting most of your answers as community wiki. Why is that?

Answer (score 5):

I only know one person IRL who I know for certain participates by posting questions and answers on Stack Overflow.  I know a few others who are aware of it from finding answers already posted on SO.

We know from numerous reports from Jeff and Joel that around 90% of Stack Overflow's traffic comes from Google, so I don't find it at all hard to believe that the vast majority of developers only use Stack Overflow passively.